# File upload field validation in Web Forms for Marketers 8.1 update 3

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore8.1

I am trying file upload validation in sitecore 8 using Web forms for Marketers but it is not working please suggest me solution. Here is my code.

```cs
namespace Test.Web.WFFM
{
  [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field)]
  public class LimitFileSizeAttribute : DynamicValidationBase
  {

    private const string FileSizeLimitKey = "filesizelimit";
    private const string ErrorMessageKey = "filesizelimiterror";

    protected override ValidationResult ValidateFieldValue(IViewModel model, object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {

        // Required attribute should handle null value
        if (value == null)
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        var fileBase = value as HttpPostedFileBase;
        if (fileBase == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(ErrorMessage);
        }

        var fileUploadField = validationContext.ObjectInstance as FileUploadField;
        var limit = GetLimit(fileUploadField);

        if (limit == -1) // Limit not set
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }

        if (fileBase.ContentLength > limit)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(GetErrorMessage(fileUploadField));
        }

        return ValidationResult.Success;
    }

    private static int GetLimit(IViewModel field)
    {
        if (field == null || !field.Parameters.ContainsKey(FileSizeLimitKey))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        var parameter = field.Parameters[FileSizeLimitKey];
        int intValue;
        if (int.TryParse(parameter, out intValue))
        {
            return intValue;
        }

        return -1;
    }

    private string GetErrorMessage(IViewModel field)
    {
        if (field != null && field.Parameters.ContainsKey(ErrorMessageKey))
        {
            return field.Parameters[ErrorMessageKey];
        }

        return ErrorMessage;
    }
}}
```

> Created RestrictedUploadField class

```cs
namespace Test.Web.WFFM.MVC
{
  public class RestrictedUploadField : FileUploadField
  { 
    [LimitFileSize]
    public override HttpPostedFileBase Value { get; set; }
}}
```

> Created custom validation in sitecore and added "Parameters" and "Localized Parameters"

[image]

[image]

Created custom field type "Restricted File Upload", added validation in "Validation" field, added "Parameters" and "Localized Parameters".
[image]

Comment: As you seem to have used the code from my blog (http://ggullentops.blogspot.be/2016/05/sitecore-wffm-mvc-fileuploadfield.html), could you tell me what is not working exactly?  Do you get an error?

Comment: Just a few thoughts: did you fill the "Localized Parameters" on the fieldtype-item with something like "<DynamicRequiredErrorMessage>The {0} field is required.</DynamicRequiredErrorMessage>". And did you fill the "Parameters" and "Localized Parameters" on the field item in the form itself?

Comment: I have added localized parameter but it is allowing me to upload more than size which I have defined

Comment: Is your attribute code being called? What happens if you debug it?

Comment: It is not coming in debug point.

Comment: Are you sure the field that is used in the form is of the correct type - the custom one? Is the form actually submitting or are there client-side validation errors? Is any other server-side validation called?

Comment: Yes it is correct.